# What option makes IE 11 sites look weird?

Tags: internet-explorer, styles, windows-8.1

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

Installed Windows 8.1 and want to use IE for emulating all IE versions for web coding , but it seems that IE transforms even google.com and yahoo.com in its own style that takes it from main windows style. Is there any option to switch it off?

Comment: Are you talking about IE or Edge?  Seems there's two separate questions there.

Comment: Harry, was looked rignt now, you right, it is IE 11

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is problem of windows 8/ windows 8.1 operating systems. That problem appears in windows 10 in internet explorer when user changing default theme appereance.